# Animation to scale items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, scale

[image]

I'm using horizontal [snapping RecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/lauw/fc84f7d04f8c54e56d56) to display the images.

```
<com.superup.smartshelf.view.SnappingRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/show_camera" />
```

Here is how images are scaled

```
private void updateViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        setMarginsForChild(child);

        if (mScaleUnfocusedViews) {
            float percentage = getPercentageFromCenter(child);
            float scale = 2.5f - (2f * percentage);

            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    }
}
```

How to proportionally scale images inside this view, when another UI element is opened (EditText onFocus, for example)? Need to scale it with animation.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to scale holder's itemView in onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int    position) 
{

 holder.itemView.animate().scaleX(1.2f);
 holder.itemView.animate().scaleY(1.2f);
}
```